# Textpipe Batch replace XML tags, but not content

Tags: xml, batch-file, csv, text, replace

I have a set of XMLs and want to replace all of the tags (including nested tags) with a , so that i can view the content between each and every tag as a field in a CSV

ie)

```
<name>John doe</name>
```

and i want to be left with just

```
,John Doe,
```

There are over 200 different tags in the xml files so i can't find and replace individual  tags.

Thanks for any help

Comment: you should better use a xml editor for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is extremely simple (and fast) to do what you ask using [a regular expression search and replace utility like REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053).

```
type file.xml | repl "<.*?>" "," >file.csv
```

But I doubt the output will be of much use.

You might consider only adding a comma for closing tags:

```
type file.xml | repl "</.*?>" "," | repl "<.*?>" "" >file.csv
```

But I still doubt it will be useful.

---

To do the above against all .XML files within a folder hierarchy:

```
for /r "c:\rootPath" %F in (*.xml) do type "%F" | repl "</.*?>" "," | repl "<.*?>" "" >"%~dpnF.csv"
```

Change all `%` to `%%` if used within a batch script.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not so good with code so would i be able to do this for a batch of files in 1 shot?  i have around 60K XMLs i need to do this with.  Also there are some other tags in the XML like <numerator value="100"> will this also catch those tags and just return the ,100,?  As far as it not being useful all im trying to do is extract all of the non-code information from the XML files and i really havent been able to find an easy way to do this otherwise.

Comment: @user2813634 - I updated the answer to show how to apply the code to many files. Of course the code will not preserve tag attributes, as you didn't ask for that. I suppose more code could be added to accomplish that, but it is only the beginning of a very slippery slope. You are likely going to run into ***many*** more problems with this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with dbenhams answer, but since I was already most of the way through writing it, I figured I'd post it anyway.

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set infile=in.txt
set outfile=out.txt

for /f "delims=" %%a in (%infile%) do call :rtags "%%a"

goto :EOF

:rtags %1
set "line=%~1"
set switch=0
set tag=
:loop
if defined line (
    if "^%line:~0,1%"=="^>" (
        set switch=0
        set tag=%tag%.
    )
    if !switch!==1 set "tag=%tag%%line:~0,1%"
    if "^%line:~0,1%"=="^<" set switch=1
    set "line=%line:~1%"
    goto :loop
)

set "line=%~1"

for %%a in (%tag:.= %) do set line=!line:^<%%a^>=,!

echo !line!>>%outfile%

goto :EOF
```

Could be quite easily modified to look at a set of files, and output to different files.